# Query Related BelongsToMany

Tags: bookshelf.js, knex.js

User Model

```
    var User = db.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      this.on('creating', this.generateId, this);
    },
    tableName: 'users',
    hasTimestamps: true,
    hidden: ['password'],
    companies: function(){
      return this.belongsToMany(
        require('./company'),
        'users_companies',
        'user_id',
        'company_id'
      )
    },
    charities: function(){
      return this.belongsToMany(
        require('./charity'),
        'users_charities',
        'user_id',
        'charity_id'
      ).withPivot(['company_id']);
    },
    generateId: function(model, attrs, options) {
      model.set('id', uuid.v4());
    }
});
```

Controller

```
exports.getAllCharities = function(req, res){
  new User({ id: req.user.id })
  .charities()
  .fetch()
  .then(function(charities){
    return res.json(charities.toJSON());
  })
```

The above works, however, I need to be able to query the returned charities to filter by the pivot field of 'company_id'. Trying charities.where({company_id: 1}).fetch(), results in an exception which says where is not a function of charities.

**Found a Solution**

```
new User({ id: req.user.id })
  .charities()
  .query('where', 'company_id', '=', req.query.companyid)
  .fetch()
  .then(function(charities){
    return res.json(charities.toJSON())
  })
```

Can someone explain the difference between that and using `.where({company_id: req.query.companyid})`

Answer (score 0):

Well, using `.where({company_id: req.query.companyid})` you're basically limiting yourself to "this - equals - that". If you use `query` you can achieve much more, e.g. `.query('where', 'age', '>', 10)`

Besides, you can use `query` a little bit different and you can tap into the knex query builder. E.g.:

```
new Person().query(function(qb) {
    qb.whereIn('id', [2, 4]);
}).fetch().then(function(){});
```

This way you can basically access everything knex.js offers: http://knexjs.org/